# FactoryGirl + RSpec + Rails 3 Engine 'undefined method'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have been trying to use FactoryGirl while developing a Rails 3 mountable engine, and when the factory is called in the spec, it returns the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `foo_bar=' for #<Foo::Baz:0x007fed6e3e2700>
```

**Models**

Foo::Bar

```
module Foo
  class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bazs
  end
end
```

Foo::Baz

```
module Foo
  class Baz < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :bar
  end
end
```

**Factories**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foo_bar, class: Foo::Bar do
    ...
  end

  factory :foo_baz, class: Foo::Baz do
    foo_bar
  end
end
```

Looking at other topics [FactoryGirl + RSpec + Rails 3 'undefined method ='](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949319/factorygirl-rspec-rails-3-undefined-method-attribute) and followed the answer and it still did not work.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the calling create from FactoryGirl using the wrong association name in my spec.

```
FactoryGirl.create(:foo_baz, foo_bar: @bar, created_at: 1.day.ago)
```

With the help that jimworm provided, it pointed me to look at the spec, so I modified the call shown below.

```
FactoryGirl.create(:foo_baz, bar: @bar, created_at: 1.day.ago)
```

This fixed the issue.

Thank you, jimworm for your help.

Answer (score 0):

An association is specified in factory_girl as `association :factory_name`.

Comment: Tried `factory :foo_baz, class: Foo::Baz do
    association :foo_bar
  end` and it did not work.  It gives the same error.

Comment: Your association is not called `foo_bar`, but `bar`. Try `association :bar, factory: :foo_bar`

Comment: I tried that and received the exact same error.  It seems to me that FactoryGirl is having a problem with the engine's namespace, but being new to Rails and FactoryGirl, I could be wrong.